# Who should be the Moderators moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice.

## Moderator Pro Tempore

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both the meta and main site.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: Little early, doncha' think?

Comment: Nope, not too early at all. This is the one time where this needs to be thought through long and hard, and give as much opportunity as possible for people to consider it. Also, you're just pouting that I beat you to it ;-)

Comment: I don't think there will be many *bad* candidates :P

Comment: It's moderators all the way down.

Comment: so I can't run in this election @AnnaLear? (I know there's not an election for pro tem mods, JK)

Comment: @rolfl I still think this is a little early as we still need to see who are the prominent users once this site gets a few questions...

Comment: Does a community full of moderators *really* need to be moderated? *kidding*

Comment: I nominated [Xzibit](http://i.imgur.com/kjQ3vwn.jpg)

Comment: To keep accusations of a Stack Exchange bias to a minimum I would suggest that no one who's a mod on another site should be a mod here. This may limit the field (at least until the first election), but I think it could be essential to the site being viable.

Comment: @ChrisF As someone who's a mod outside of SE, and not on any SE site, I have to say I don't share your concern.

Comment: Okay, yes, this isn't _literally_ a duplicate, but that's the best option for closing this obsolete post short of setting up a whole custom close reason.

Comment: @Pops - Historical Lock?

Answer (score 25):

[image: profile for Andy at Moderators Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

I am an administrator/site owner of a medium sized gaming community that runs on a PHPBB3 board. We host multiple game servers as well. I've got a team of moderators that help keep the forum and game servers clean. I've run this site for 5 years, after taking it over from the original creator of the community who wanted to move on. In my time as admin, we've seen the number of participants on the forum increase. We've seen our game server population increase as well. I attribute this to getting the community involved in change discussions.

One of our biggest changes occurred several years ago. Community members complained that our game servers would be over run with trolls at hours when moderators weren't available and spewing filth. The community wanted a cleaner game server experience. Users wanted these players gone immediately. Previous community leaders felt that trolling of this kind was part of the game and did nothing. After some discussions regarding what was and wasn't appropriate, we decided to be (for lack of a better term) "family friendlier". Certain 'extreme' phrases were no longer tolerated at all. A technical solution was built to automatically remove players that violated these rules. This solution allowed users to swear, but once it became excessive (again, defined by the community) they, too, were removed.

The tool we have (PHPBB3) may not have the reputation, badges, or increasing privileges used here on Stack Exchange but for my community that has not been a negative. Engaging with the community in discussions and letting the members provide input that me and my team utilize has been extremely beneficial.

I have no experience moderating a Stack Exchange site. I don't feel that's a down side though. I can provide the "outside" perspective in a Stack Exchange heavy group. That does mean, though, that I'd depend on and expect the community to provide feedback on how moderation in being handled. Much like my existing gaming community, input from the community to the moderation team is important and the moderation team should be listening to that input.

Comment: I am very glad to see you here and actively participating.  You bring a much-needed perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @MonicaCellio.

Comment: It'll definitely be nice to have a moderator here who isn't a SE mod elsewhere, and you've contributed plenty of high-quality content both on main and meta. You have my vote!

Comment: I've worked with Andy in [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), and I think he'd be an excellent moderator. He is very active both here and elsewhere on the network. Good luck!

Answer (score 17):

[image: profile for AJ Henderson at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

I guess I'll throw my hat in the ring as well.  As someone who has been a moderator on IRC, forums, games, wikipedia and currently on multiple SE sites, as well as having led in person debates, I'm familiar with a broad range of moderation environments and topics.  This set of experience ideally prepares me for being able to understand the relationships between different types of moderation.

That said, I do also think we should make sure at least one pro temp moderator is someone without previous SE moderator experience that is primarily currently active in moderating another community if such a user steps forward.

Comment: That last paragraph is going to be awful hard to do with our current userbase :/

Answer (score 14):

I would like to nominate Monica Cellio.

[image: profile for Monica Cellio at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]


[image: profile for Monica Cellio at Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites]


[profile for Monica Cellio on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/505925.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/505925)

In particular, I've been impressed by the way Monica's contributions on the main site explicitly acknowledge the diversity of perspectives that exist within every community.

Monica's answers demonstrate an ability to communicate clearly and effectively and an appreciation for how nuanced a job moderation and community building can be. Those are precisely the qualities I would look for in choosing a moderator for a community full of moderators.

Hopefully the added responsibility on a fourth (!) SE network site isn't asking too much of this user, who I think would bring a unique and valuable perspective to our übermoderator dream team .

Comment: Thank you for the kind words and the votes of confidence. Currently I am a mod on three othere SE sites, the busiest of which is currently down to two mods. I don't feel I can take this on at this time; if an additional mod is needed in six months or so that may be different. Meanwhile, I look forward to continuing to participate as a user with, I hope, useful contributions to make. :-)

Comment: Usually the problem is that "6 to 8 weeks" becomes "6 to 8 months", but in this case it's the reverse: our new moderator on that site came in with a ton of clue and other stuff has settled down. I'm very glad to see AJ's new appointment; should someone else be needed in the future I'm now open to that -- though I'm quite happy to just be a regular user, we have an excellent team now, and none of y'all should go anywhere!

Answer (score 9):

[image: profile for FEichinger at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for FEichinger at Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites]
[profile for FEichinger on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1945575.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1945575/feichinger)

As we're setting up for a lot of self-"nominations", I'll join here as well: My name is Frederic Eichinger. I have experience with moderation stemming from various times as administrator or moderator of communities including board game enthusiast forums, official video game communities, and smaller project boards, overall amounting to roughly six years of experience. I have seen different teams handle different situations, and I have been a cornerstone of balanced decision-making in most of these teams. This experience is what drove me towards supporting this site to begin with.

My activity on Stack Exchange is usually related to the meta sites more than the main sites - building the community, helping with site-related issues, and establishing policy. I had been watching the area51 proposal for a while, particularly regarding the **community** focus, and I'm looking forward to seeing us put the naming arguments behind us so we can actually give expert advice on *building, managing, and maintaining* communities of all sorts.

With my SE activity spread across multiple sites and focused largely in chat lately, I am easily able to dedicate a decent amount of my currently free time to assisting and cleaning up on moderators.SE as well.

Answer (score -1):

[image: profile for omeinusch at Moderators Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for community managers, administrators, and moderators]
 

[profile for omeinusch on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2687565.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/2687565)

My name is Oliver Meinusch (obviously) and I am the administrator of a large community of a game series in the german area. Moderating once a forum for Ubisoft and having my own community with 23k+ users and 560k+ posts, I changed my focused but stack exchange is my favourite <strike>forum</strike> community network. I am a close to daily visitor and had my experience with IRC, too.

I was never a moderator of any stack exchange network nor am I a high reputation user (~1.7k in total). But I will give my best and I am very very curious how to moderator a stack exchange website. The topic of this new child is still fascinating for me and I am sure that I will give my best to be a valuable member of this community.

Comment: You haven't been very active here on meta, and some of your activity on main also is slightly lacking (commenting, editing, close-voting, etc.). Do you still think you'll be able to be an effective moderator of the community, despite this?

Comment: Some will be concerned that you consider Stack Exchange to be a 'forum' .... [it is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/241497) despite what [wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange) *The sites are modeled after Stack Overflow, a forum for computer programming questions*

Comment: Stackexchange *is* a forum. Because of all those traditional internet fora, some might think that a forum consists of threads, replies and private messages, but that's not nearly the only possible format. A forum is any place/website where people can convene for discussions about certain topics.

Comment: Thank you for your questions. That you question me, means, you take me serious. @Doorknob Yes I do. Like everybody else, I have a live beside SE and I think it's not necessary to be fulltime to click on moderators.SE. More important is, that I visit the site on a frequent and regulray base.

Comment: @rolfl Good point, I was unprecise in my wording. I ask you to forgive me and corrected by forum. I know the differences between SE and a regulra forum.

Comment: @LeeWhite - yes, but that's just it, SE isn't supposed to be about discussing a topic.  In fact, outside of meta, if something becomes a discussion, we shut it down, or at least try to.  SE is a repository of questions and answers, we work to try and improve those answers, but we don't have discussions about what a proper answer would be (on the main sites).

Comment: I definitely see your point. SE is not like conventional forums. But despite the unique format, in the end, it is not wrong to refer to SE as a forum.